# Replace element in list

Tags: haskell

I have a simple question about list in haskell. (I am a beginner in haskell)

I would know how can i replace an element in an array but as simple as possible.

```
[1, 2, 4, 4, 5]
```

to

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And also how can i happend a number to a list

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

to

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have already read that tutorial : http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

I was thinking about this for the first problem :

```
array = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5]
array[2] = 2
```

and that for the second :

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array ++ [5]
```

Ps : the `array ++ [5]` works with ghci but when i do like that in code :

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

modifyarray = do
print $ array !! 2
array ++ [5]
print $ array !! 4
```

that doesn't work ...

EDIT :

```
module Main where

import Lib
import System.Environment
import System.Exit

redPoint = [3,4,2]

fillArray file x = do
    let line = lines file
    print $ line

replaceAt x y = map (\(i,v) -> if (i==x) then y else v) . zip [1..]

replaceArray = do
    print $ redPoint !! 2
    replaceAt 2 9 redPoint
    print $ redPoint !! 2

openfile a n path = do
    file <- readFile path
    fillArray file 0
    replaceArray

exit = exitWith ExitSuccess
error_exit = exitWith (ExitFailure 84)

parse [a, n, path] = openfile a n path >> exit
parse [] = error_exit

main = do
    getArgs >>= parse
```

This error :

> Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
>         Expected type: IO Integer
>           Actual type: [Integer]
>       • In a stmt of a 'do' block: replaceAt 2 9 redPoint
>         In the expression:
>           do print $ redPoint !! 2
>              replaceAt 2 9 redPoint
>              print $ redPoint !! 2
>         In an equation for ‘replaceArray’:
>             replaceArray
>               = do print $ redPoint !! 2
>                    replaceAt 2 9 redPoint
>                    print $ redPoint !! 2

Comment: For the latter you need to append with a *list*, not a (scalar) number.

Comment: like array ++ [5] ?

Comment: yes, like `++ [5]`

Comment: look edit ... that works with ghci but i don't now how to implement that in code

Comment: ok for the ones who will need help I found (but don't know if that's the most optimize)

For array[2] = 4      in Haskell ---->      let array !! 2 = 4

Comment: **immutable** is the concept you need to internalize

Comment: That `let` thing overwrites the (!!) operator.

Comment: Looking at your program, it seems you are trying to change the value of `redPoint`. Haskell was designed to prevent the mutation of values. If you let `x = 3`, then any `print x` in the program will mean `print 3`, since there is no way to change the value bound to `x`. Similarly, if `redPoint` is defined as a given list, `print redPoint` will always print that list -- there is no way to change that value. In Haskell, you can only create _new_ values out of old ones, but you can not overwrite old values.

Comment: So there is no way to change a value of a list @chi ? I have to create an other one ?

Comment: Exactly. The function `replaceAt` below won't change the existing list, but will create and return a new list, equal to the previous one, with a different element. Luckily, in Haskell we don't need arrays as much as we do in imperative languages, so this is not a real issue. In those cases where we really need arrays, we have libraries for those (`Array`, `Vector`, ...) and ways to recover performance and simulate mutation (e.g. `IO` and `STs` monads), but these should be considered advanced topics -- if you are a beginner, learn the basics of the language first, using a tutorial like LYAH.

Comment: I count two questions. Ask one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

you don't do mutation on the list but create a new list from the given list.

an example, without any error handling...

```
> replaceAt x y = map (\(i,v) -> if (i==x) then y else v) . zip [1..]
> replaceAt 3 10 [1..5]

[1,2,10,4,5]
```

create an indexed list by zipping with the counting numbers, write a map function to change the value at the desired index.

Comment: I have this error : Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO Integer
        Actual type: [Integer]

I really don't understand why that's not working (sorry i am a beginner)

Comment: copy/pasted to Prelude and got this error?  Not sure where the `IO` is coming from?

Comment: i have only this line : import System.IO
with IO 

I can show you the code (it's short and simple)

Comment: No explicit import is needed to run this code in Prelude.  IO will complicate things for you at this stage.

Comment: I edit the post with all the code (all is working : the code is reading a file (that's working) and it modify a global list)

Comment: *"it modifies a global list"* is the **big** misconception.  There is no list modification, the function will return you another list.  I think you're trying to jump before you can walk.  Take your time to internalize fundamentals before writing full programs.

Answer (score 1):

Lens! (Maybe it is overhead but anyway)

```
_drop 0 = id
_drop n = _tail . _drop (n - 1)
```

And use case

```
[1..5] & _drop 1 %~ (5:) -- [1,5,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lens

```
> import Control.Lens

Control.Lens> [1..5] & (ix 1) .~ 5
[1,5,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please ask only one question in a single post.

Here is an implementation which doesn't use Lens and more suitable for a beginner. The `replaceAt` function error handling needs some brain work. Without error handling it could be fitted in a single line.

These functions work on infinite lists, too. Execution time of `replaceAt` depends of *i*. Replacing element in the end of the list is slower than in the beginning because of the recursive nature of Haskell's lists.

```haskell
module ListOperations where

replaceAt :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceAt i x xs = case (i<0, splitAt i xs) of
  (False,(start,(_:end))) -> start ++ (x:end)
  _                       -> error "Index out of bounds"

append :: a -> [a] -> [a]
append x xs = xs ++ [x]
```